# force docker-compose push/pull

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose

I have a jenkins job that builds all my docker images and pushes them to my docker hub. It then ssh to the server on which I want to deploy and runs docker-compose pull && docker-compose up.

For some reason, this mechanism is not handling changes in the dockers well. I changed one of my requirements in one of the images. I can see in jenkins that it recognized the change and did not use the cache for that stage:

```
Step 16/33 : RUN ldconfig
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 15284e3997f6
Step 17/33 : ADD requirements.txt requirements.txt
 ---> 1c2d81548e55
Step 18/33 : RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in 679034a149d4
Collecting alembic==0.9.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
```

you can see here that step 16 was still using cache and step 17 did not. Which is working as expected.

I then push the images:

```
-------------
Publishing Images
-------------

    Pushing base (<docker-hub-server>/base:latest)...
    The push refers to repository [<docker-hub-server>/base].
```

After that I ssh to the server and pull the image.

The problem is that for some reason, the new image with the updated dependecies was not pushed for some reason.

I tried removing all containers and images both in the jenkins server and in the destination server.

This feels like is something is being cached incorrectly.

im looking for a solution that will force push that image to the repo, or something similar.

Edit:

more info:

```
The push refers to repository [<docker-hub-server>/base]
9430005e84f9: Preparing
48e6dda22a29: Preparing
972483a80c7c: Preparing
a534cbaa9205: Preparing
23b2691ba244: Preparing
0f29e137999a: Layer already exists
b154080f7784: Layer already exists
0c7778ab05f8: Layer already exists
b2a1e0120631: Layer already exists
a597ec0005e2: Layer already exists
a5dc291ad4b4: Layer already exists
c54dfcd94152: Layer already exists
3415f7db917e: Layer already exists
0c01967aaa96: Layer already exists
7f969e99b7b3: Layer already exists
45652f92e451: Layer already exists
4acd815bd647: Layer already exists
72a531f31293: Layer already exists
b9624af892c1: Layer already exists
3c0dc8487715: Layer already exists
d54136b410c5: Layer already exists
cc349f2a25e3: Layer already exists
b8b4502cfe14: Layer already exists
a2bc3f3bafb5: Layer already exists
db067458dfa6: Layer already exists
ccec44bf5310: Layer already exists
a1ae7010d9f9: Layer already exists
03a6b6877a9b: Layer already exists
ef68f6734aa4: Layer already exists
```

After checking in jenkins, the right image is there, but still when I push it says that all layers already exist even though Step 16, 17 were changed.

Comment: Can you compare the SHA-Keys of the images / layers?

Comment: Should the SHA-Keys of the steps be the same as the layers that are pushed? they aren't in my case..

Comment: in effect, the sha-keys of a pushed image should be the same as the local one

Comment: What else can I do if its not? I pruned my system. Is there any way to force push it or delete the image on docker hub so it'll update it?

Comment: is it possible that docker-compose push is not pushing the right image (latest)?

Answer (score -2):

use --no-cache option while building the docker image and check if this solves the problem

Comment: As I said in the question, the problem is not in the build - but in the pushing to docker-hub. I ran docker prune system -a and that didnt work.  so its no surprise that --no-cache didnt work as well.